# Differences in 'for' syntax on Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

While porting my code from Python 2 to Python 3, the following function could not execute:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def func(x, y, z):
    x, y, z = [Decimal(arg) for arg in x, y, z]
    # function continues...
```

In Python 3, I had to change it to `x, y, z = [Decimal(arg) for arg in [x, y, z]]`.

Question #1:

Is that piece of code even legal under Python 2 standard, or did my interpreter just happened to be "forgiving"?

Question #2:

Are there any similar ("list-related") differences that I should be aware of?

Comment: It is a shame that the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) closed..

Comment: Note, this is [mentioned in the What's New for Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax), but there's no explanation of why.

Comment: @DanielRoseman [from the BDFL](https://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html)

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, interesting post. I wish he'd continued that series...